# Can't figure out why my text isn't turning into green

Tags: javascript, html, css

First of all, here are my codes.

```js
    var p1 = document.querySelector(".playerOne");
    var p2 = document.querySelector(".playerTwo");
    var p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Span");
    var p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Span");
    var header = document.querySelector("h1");
    var reset = document.querySelector(".reset");
    //var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var until = document.getElementsByClassName(".until");
    var p1Score = 0;
    var p2Score = 0;
    var gameOver = false;
    var max = 5;
    
    p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (!gameOver) {
            p1Score++;
            p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
            header.textContent = (p1Score + " to " + p2Score);
        } 
        if (p1Score === max) {
            p1Display.classList.add("winner");
            gameOver = true;
        }
    });
    p2.addEventListener("click", function() {
        if (!gameOver) {
            p2Score++;
            p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
            header.textContent = (p1Score + " to " + p2Score);
        } 
        if (p2Score === max) {
            p2Display.classList.add("winner");
            gameOver = true;
        }
    });
    reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
        gameOver = false;
        p1Score = 0;
        p2Score = 0;
        p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
        p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
        header.textContent = (p1Score + " to " + p2Score);
    });
```

```css
    .winner {
        color: green;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title>JS practice 2</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1><span id="p1Span">0</span> to <span id="p2Span">0</span></h1>
        <p class="until">Playing to: </p>
        <input type="number">
        <button class="playerOne">Player One</button>
        <button class="playerTwo">Player Two</button>
        <button class="reset">Reset</button>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
        
    </body>
    </html>
```

So, as you can see, my p1Display and p2Display should turn into green.
The problem is, they don't do that, while they pick the class winner up at 5 points. Why it isn't turning into green while it has the class that turns it into green?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to remove this code in all functions:

header.textContent = (p1Score + " to " + p2Score);

Also you should remove the same line from the reset funcion and update p1Display.textContent and p2Display.textContent to make that function works.

```
reset.addEventListener("click", function () {
    gameOver = false;
    p1Score = 0;
    p2Score = 0;

    p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
    p2Display.textContent = p2Score;

    p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
    p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
    //header.textContent = (p1Score + " to " + p2Score);
});
```

Regards!

Answer (score 3):

You are erasing the `span` by changing the content of the `h1` each time. No need to do it since you are already changing the content of the `span`. So you have to remove this:

`header.textContent = (p1Score + " to " + p2Score);`

```js
var p1 = document.querySelector(".playerOne");
var p2 = document.querySelector(".playerTwo");
var p1Display = document.querySelector("#p1Span");
var p2Display = document.querySelector("#p2Span");
var header = document.querySelector("h1");
var reset = document.querySelector(".reset");
//var input = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
var until = document.getElementsByClassName(".until");
var p1Score = 0;
var p2Score = 0;
var gameOver = false;
var max = 5;

p1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    p1Score++;
    p1Display.textContent = p1Score;
  }
  if (p1Score === max) {
    p1Display.classList.add("winner");
    gameOver = true;
  }
});
p2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (!gameOver) {
    p2Score++;
    p2Display.textContent = p2Score;
  }
  if (p2Score === max) {
    p2Display.classList.add("winner");
    gameOver = true;
  }
});
reset.addEventListener("click", function() {
  gameOver = false;
  p1Score = 0;
  p2Score = 0;
  p1Display.classList.remove("winner");
  p2Display.classList.remove("winner");
});
```

```css
.winner {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<h1><span id="p1Span">0</span> to <span id="p2Span">0</span></h1>
<p class="until">Playing to: </p>
<input type="number">
<button class="playerOne">Player One</button>
<button class="playerTwo">Player Two</button>
<button class="reset">Reset</button>
```